# Custom field value not getting saved?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created one custom blog module. For adminpanel Post form i have one field named "identifier". When i save the form all field values getting saved except the "identifier" field.I have tried following too

```
public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('post')) {
        try {
            $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('post_date'));
            $post = $this->_initPost(); 
            $post->setData('identifier', $data['identifier']);
            $post->addData($data);                              
            $post->save();
```

But not getting saved. Please help me.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: @Marius , Yes. In live server only i am getting this problem.In local its getting saved when i add `$post->setData('identifier', $data['identifier']);`. But in live its not working.

Comment: This issue usually appears when you add a table field after the module is installed. The table schema is cached even if cache is disabled. Usually, clearing the cache solved the problem. If you are using an alternative way of cacheing (apc, redis, memcached) on the live server make sure you clear that also. restarting the service should do the trick.

Comment: @Marius, i always delete var/cache folder itself.Is there any problem with that?

Comment: Don't delete the var/cache folder. Just it's contents.

Comment: @Marius,Thanks. But its not working.Please share any suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code as below

```
        $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('post_date'));
        $post = $this->_initPost(); 
        $post->addData($data);                              
        $post->setData('identifier', $data['identifier']);
        $post->save();
```